# The concept behind scipy.signal.medfilt2d in python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

I am trying to understand how scipy.signal.medfilt2d works. After I looked at the scipy documentation, its format is:

scipy.signal.medfilt2d(input, kernel_size=3)

So like if I have a matrix like

```
1 2 3 7 2 4
3 4 2 2 6 7
1 7 3 1 2 6
3 2 3 4 3 1
2 6 7 8 2 5
3 4 2 2 1 8
```

Since the kernel size is set to 3 in default. If I apply medfilt2d to this matrix, will the matrix become the one like below? ( what I did is take every element inside the 3 x 3 box, add them all up and divide by 9 ( average) )

```
2.8   2.8   2.8   4.1   4.1  4.1
2.8   2.8   2.8   4.1   4.1  4.1
2.8   2.8   2.8   4.1   4.1  4.1
3.5   3.5   3.5   3.7   3.7  3.7
3.5   3.5   3.5   3.7   3.7  3.7
3.5   3.5   3.5   3.7   3.7  3.7
```

So please share your knowledge and insight with me? Tell me if I am wrong so I can learn from this mistake. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/signal.html#median-filter), `medfilt2` is a median filter. Quoting from the documentation,

```
The sample median is the middle array value in a sorted list of neighborhood values
```

So for your example, the submatrix at position `1,1`

```
1 2 3
3 4 2
1 7 3
```

would be sorted into

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 7
```

The middle element is `3` so that would be the output of the filter.  There's more detail [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).

Comment: so do you mean the first quarters of my second matrix should filled with "3" instead of "2.8"?

Comment: No, each element in your second matrix can have a different result. For element `0,0`, the input submatrix will be `[[0,0,0],[0,1,2],[0,3,4]]` (internally, the subroutine pads your matrix with 0's to fill in the missing elements). Then the sorted list is `[0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4]` and the median element is `0`. For element `0,1` the submatrix is `[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[3,4,2]]` -> `[0,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,4]` -> `2` and so forth.

Comment: oh I totally get what you are saying now. I have a question: I need a way that can enhance the resolution of an image and reduce the resolution of an image? If applying medfilt2d is to reduce the resolution, are there any other filter to enhance the resolution? Thanks a lot

Comment: As far as I know, median filters are for noise removal, not resolution change. You probably want to look into resampling filters.